# TabLayoutPanel finish loading event

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I use a GWT TabLayoutPanel which contains several Google Charts Widgets.

I want to know if there's a handler/method that can be called once all the widgets in the tab have finished loading.(after I click the tab)

I need this because I refresh/reload the Charts once I click the tab, but the charts MUST be loaded first or the height/width won't apply on the charts.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get UI widgets by Iterating or something like widget.getElementBytagName(). You should try gwt.Document.DOMHandler. widget.addDomHandler can get to iterate its sub widget or everythings under this widget. Really you don't need to invoke handlers to each widget. Try with DOMHandler. This can be OK. I don't know clearly what you really want to do. Please describe with your codes as you can.

Comment: thanks, what I was trying to do is to find a way to know when all thw widgets of a specified panel finished loading using TabLayoutPanel.